# Cocos2d-x 3.x rendering with and without spritesheet

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, alphablending

I am rendering a flower from textures from a spritesheet on screen, and all looks fine. When I use the same textures but not from a spritesheet the flower is rendered differently.

This image (first, below) of the flower rendered from a spritesheet and looks correctly. It is composed of two texture layers: petals and center.

[image: image of flower rendered correctly]

This image (below) of the flower composed from two sprites, one holding petals texture, the other holding the center texture, not from a spritesheet. As you can see, there is transparency around the center, and that is caused by (I presume) blending of center texture onto the petals texture.

[image: image of flower rendered incorrectly]

The petals and center textures were composed from original images read from files using CCRenderTexture. The original images are PMA (premultiplied-alpha), while the resulting texture from CCRenderTexture is NPMA (non-premultiplied-alpha).

Changing blending modes to PMA or NPMA does not help.

The sprite node hierarchy is simple:

```
ROOT-SPRITE (empty image, ie 1x1px size, fully tranparent image)
  PETALS-SPRITE (petals texture), z=1
  CENTER-SPRITE (center texture), z=2
```

I have the following questions:

What am I doing wrong?
How can I resolve this?

Using Cocos2D-X v3.4 in iOS simulator (device has same results).

Comment: Which sprite scaling issues do you refer to?  Maybe, but what is an enigma to me is the transparency "ring" around the center of the flower.  I'm sure it's a blending issue, but, what am I doing wrong?  Am I blending incorrectly from the original image into the center texture, or am I blending incorrectly the center texture together with the petals texture into the resulting CCRenderTexture?  I wrote out the intermediary images to png files, but they all look fine??  So, where have I gone wrong?

Comment: No, you're right. I was I guess, not fully awake when I wrote that =P The two images are different scales and once you sort that out, it is basically just the purple ring that's causing problems. I will delete that comment.